# UITableView-upon scrolling it loses properties associated with selected cells. How to save these properties? - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an application with a custom popup that holds a tableview (see below).  When I tap on a check box(UIButton), i swap out the background image and toggle between checked and unchecked.  When I have a checked box, when I scroll up or down, the checked box defaults back to unchecked.  Please could someone advise on how to keep the checked status of each cell upon scrolling?

[image]

```
 class CustomHashTagPopup: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


// CREATE TABLEVIEW CELLS
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableViewPicker.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pickerCell") as! PreviewTableViewCustomPickerCell

    if(indexPath == [0,0]){
        let image = UIImage.init(named: "add")
        cell.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(image!, for: .normal)
        cell.pickerLabel.text = "Create New HashTag"
        cell.isCreateTagCell = true

    }else{
        let image = UIImage.init(named: "uncheck")
        cell.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(image!, for: .normal)
        cell.pickerLabel.text = arrayHashTags[indexPath.row]
        cell.isCreateTagCell = false
    }
    return cell

}


 }


 class PreviewTableViewCustomPickerCell: UITableViewCell {

 var isSelect: Bool = false
var isCreateTagCell: Bool = false // TO DISTINGUISH 'CEATE NEW HASHTAG OPTION'



/*** OUTLETS ***/

@IBOutlet weak var checkBoxOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerLabel: UILabel!


 // TAP ON CHECK BOX
@IBAction func checkBoxBtn(_ sender: Any) {


    if(isSelect == false && isCreateTagCell == false){
        isSelect = true
        // SHOW GREEN SELECTED CHECK BOX
        let image = UIImage.init(named: "tick")
        self.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(image!, for: .normal)

    }else if(isSelect == true && isCreateTagCell == false){
        isSelect = false
        // SHOW UNCHECKED BOX
        let image = UIImage.init(named: "uncheck")
        self.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(image!, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you miss is cell-reusing , you have to store every action inside the model array and check the current value and set the appropriate settings inside `cellForRowAt` , you may set the delegate of the actions to the vc for the buttons inside `cellForRowAt` for ease access of the model array to manipulate it as the user clicks that button at a specific indexPath , so conside declaring array like this

```
let arr = [false,true,false,false,false] first index is dummy as it will be skipped in Create New HashTag
```

//

```
@objc func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
   arr[sender.tag] = !arr[sender.tag]
    // reload indexPath of row = sender.tag , section = 0
}
```

//

Inside `cellForRowAt`

```
if (indexPath == [0,0]) {
    let image = UIImage(named: "add")
    cell.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(image!, for: .normal)
    cell.pickerLabel.text = "Create New HashTag"
    cell.isCreateTagCell = true

}else{
    let image = UIImage(named: arr[indexPath.row] ? "tick" : "uncheck") // edited here 
    cell.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(image!, for: .normal)
    cell.pickerLabel.text = arrayHashTags[indexPath.row]
    cell.isCreateTagCell = false
}

cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```